# calculating firebase - firestore export pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backup, bucket

I have a 50GB firestore DB and around 10m documents to read
i have a blaze plan but in the bucket calculator there is a "class operation" that i did not understand.

how much should I pay per backup ? , do i need to calculate the reading firebase operations only ?
what is the price for GIB in the bucket

i tried to calculate smth like :

```
 (10,000,000 / 100,000 ) * 0.06
```

is that the price ?
i would like to know what is the pricing per backup

Comment: "n the bucket calculator there is a "class operation" that i did not understand" => See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes?_ga=2.184769248.-853558546.1590684957

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thx still did no get it
if i run gcloud firestore export 
what is the price ?
do i pay smth to class operations ? becuase its only export 

if there is lot of file on the obejct(folder), doest is mean smth ?

can you help me with calculation ?

50gb +10m documents 
i want to export 1 perday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to calculate the Firestore reading operations only?

No. As you have noticed, and as explained in the doc, "exporting data from Cloud Firestore will incur **one read operation per document exported**."

**But** there are some extra costs: Storage Cost (see below), Cloud Functions invocations cost (normally should be 0$ since there is a generous free tier of 2M/month), Cloud Scheduler cost (again there is a [free tier of 3 free jobs per month](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/pricing), per billing account).

> What is the price for GIB in the bucket?

For calculating the Storage cost, you have to take into account the [storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) of the bucket that is going to receive the exports, because the pricing depends on the class.

In the Firebase console, when you create a new bucket, you can choose the location and the desired class, see the below screenshot. They both influence de [Storage pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). Depending on your exact need, I would recommend choosing the *Rare* or *Archive* access frequency. Rare corresponds to the **Coldline** class and Archive to the **Archive** class.

[image]

Comment: @Renuad 
thanks 
lets say i choose standart
what will the price for 50GB object 
do i need to pay for class operations A ? becuase i see its so expensive 
the question is how to calcucalte how much class A operation i need

also i set lifecycle to delete the file after 7 days

Comment: To calculate the price, pls look at the doc and/or use the [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). As mentioned  in the answer it depends on the Location and the Storage class of your bucket. You can find these info in the Google Cloud [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser).

Comment: @Renuad 
thanks again 

standart + us-cental low 
my main quesiton is how much Class A opertaion do I need per 1 backup, this is smth i dont understand 
do i need 1 class operation per document?

Comment: Can you point me to the doc where you find "Class A operation"?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

@Renuad. to calcualte read operation in firebase is easy 
but what is hiding for me is how to calculate the data that sit in the standart bucket and how many operation per 1 export will be